# duplicate records, keep one with special condition

Tags: microsoft-excel, duplicate

i have duplicate records in excel sheet , with only one different column (it is a number between 11 to 19)

i need to keep one of the duplicates with the lowest number in different column, for example i have this:

```
Jack Johnson 11
Jack Johnson 12
Maria Patterson 15
Maria Patterson 16
```

i need :

```
Jack Johnson 11
Maria Patterson 15
```

any idea?

I have tried the duplicate removing but it didn't help.

Comment: sort the data on the second column first then use remove duplicates.

Comment: Do as Scott recommends, and when using remove duplicates, make sure to deselect the column with the numbers in it.

Answer (score 0):

*An array (CSE) formula can solve the issue:*

[image]

- Formula in Cell `N13`, finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill
  across.

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX(N$2:N$10, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($N$12:N12, $N$2:$N$10), 0)),"")}
  ```

**N.B.**

- *If you are handling huge data set then, better first apply `Custom Sort`, on range `N1:O10` (include Header), then apply the suggested array (CSE) formula.*

---

**Before Custom Sort when data in Random order:**

[image]

---

**After Custom Sort & the formula applied:**

[image]

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: thanks for your respond. what should i write in O13?

Comment: Glad to help you @nafiseramezani,, if you are talking about `IFERROR(INDEX(,,,` you need to write array formula in `N13` & drag it to Right then down, the formula automatically fill in `O13:O17` ,, keep asking !!

Comment: @nafiseramezani,, happy to learn that it works ,you may accept it as answer as well up vote also ☺